# sending dbus message from chromeOS to Concierge/Cicerone shows error

Tags: google-chrome-os

i am trying to send a dbus message within the chromeos terminal to actually shutdown the vm.

there is a dbus-api for that
either
https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/platform/system_api/+/master/dbus/vm_cicerone/dbus-constants.h
or
https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/platform/system_api/+/master/dbus/vm_concierge/dbus-constants.h

i always get:
The name org.chromium.VmCicerone was not provided by any .service files /
The name org.chromium.VmConcierge was not provided by any .service files

i am trying to call the method StopVm respectively ContainerShutdown

it seems that the cicerone service or concierge service is not running.

any idea, what i am doing wrong, or why the serivce is not running?

thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: to be very specific, the context menu on the terminal has an entry "shutdown linux", which really shuts down the vm. same as  "vmc stop termina" in crosh. I am looking for a possibility to execute that command within the terminal. "sudo shutdown -h now"  or "sudo halt" don't really shutdown the vm. so i tried to use the dbus-send command, that did not work though. any command within the terminal that does the same as the ui button is appreciated